# Invariant Probability of Continuous Markov Chain Made into Discrete Makov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Here’s a homework problem I was stuck on. Note that $\alpha(x,x) :=\sum_{y\neq x}\alpha(y,x)$.

*Suppose $\alpha$ gives the rates for an irreducible continuous-time Markov chain on a finite state space. Suppose the invariant probability measure is $\pi$. Let $$p(x,y) = \alpha(x,y)/\alpha(x,x), x \neq y,$$ be the probability for a discrete-time Markov chain corresponding to the continuous-time chain”when it moves”. Find the invariant probability for the discrete-time chain in terms of $\pi$ and $\alpha$.*

I tried looking at $P:=[p(x,y)]$ in terms of a combination of $A:=[\alpha(x,y) \textrm{ if } x \neq y, -\alpha(x,x) \textrm{ otherwise}]$ and some other matrix that could be easily raised to the n-th power, but I couldn’t find such a nice combination. Am I on the right track here, or is there another approach I’m missing?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the 2 state case for some intuition. Any nondegenerate 2 state chain will have its jump chain given by $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ regardless of how you pick the $\alpha$. So for these the invariant distribution of the jump chain is always $(1/2,1/2)$. But clearly the invariant measure of the original chain isn't universal: if you have $Q=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ a & -a \end{bmatrix}$ then you can see that $\pi$ is proportional to $(a,1)$.

The intuitive explanation is that it comes from the average holding time in $2$ being $a$ times shorter than the holding time in $1$. The jump chain doesn't care about the holding time; in effect it makes all the holding times deterministically equal to $1$. Thus it makes the holding time at $x$ become $\alpha(x,x)$ times as long as it is on average in the original chain.

This suggests that the invariant distribution of the jump chain might just be proportional to $\alpha(x,x) \pi(x)$. Check that this is actually correct.